# Get the first JSON object from a file containing a sequence of JSON objects

Tags: json, stream, jq

I have a file containing a sequence of json objects. Using the jq tool, how can I get the first json object from that file?

I have tried `jq limit(1; .) input.jsonl` but that limits the length of each individual object in the file, rather than giving me just the first object. I have also read through the whole of the jq man page! Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Show us a snippet of the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Null input (`-n`) is useful in such a case:

```
jq -n 'input' file.json
```

The [`input` filter](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#input) will read a single JSON element from the provided input stream.

Example:

```
jq -n 'input' <<JSON
{ "first element": [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "second element": [ 3, 4, 5 ] }
JSON
```

Output:

```
{
  "first element": [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an input file like

```json
{
  "a": "b"
}
{
  "c": "d"
}
```

you could

- slurp the entire input and then print the first array element:

  ```bash
  $ jq -s '.[0]' in.json 
  {
    "a": "b"
  }
  ```
- use null-input, and then `inputs`:

  ```bash
  $ jq -n '[inputs][0]' in.json 
  {
    "a": "b"
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Well okay one way to do it is like this:

```
jq -c . INPUT.JSONL  | head -n 1 | jq
```

The -c option says to output the entries one per line, then `head` gets the first line, then we pretty-print it again with jq. Surely there is a way to do this with just a single invokation of jq?